# Create automatically PDF from article and include them as attachment in Mail in Drupal

Tags: email, pdf, drupal, drupal-7, pdf-generation

On my Drupal 7 site, I create PDF's of articles with the [Printer, email and PDF versions Module](https://drupal.org/project/print). So a PDF version of each article is available at

```
/printpdf/nid
```

The next thing is that Im sending this articles as Newsletters with the [Simplenews Module](https://drupal.org/project/simplenews). I want to attach the created PDF as attachment to the mail.

If there is a field for a file in the Contenttype, and for example another pdf is uploaded and I send this node, the pdf is attached to the mail.

But in my case i want to create a pdf of this article and attach the pdf to the mail which is sending with simplenews module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the Problem by writing an own module.

This module uses hook_node_submit to create a PDF (with domPDF), save it to the server and then place it into a field of the contenttype when a node is saved or edited.

This way the PDF is sent as attachement in the Mail.